# Black widow perk output

Tags: fallout-4

In the description of this perk it is said that men are easier/much easier to persuade. Does it have some kind of additional charisma equivalent? E.g. 1 level of this perk is like adding 2 charisma when speaking to men or does it have different mechanics?

Comment: That's a good question. If it increases the percentage chance, like adding 10%, but that doesn't directly equate to the bonus from a specific charisma buff, is that a yes or a no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear to have an impact on charisma, per se, but according to this site, there is a bonus to persuasion chance, which is broken down as follows:

> Persuasion mechanics for this Perk are simple: Rank 1 Black Widow/Lady Killer gives a 10% easier chance to persuade, Rank 2 20%, and Rank 3 a whopping 30% increase to persuade in dialog.

Source: http://www.carls-fallout-4-guide.com/special-stats/charisma/perks/black-widow-lady-killer.php

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it affects Charisma at all.

See here: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Widow

It seems that 'sometimes gives you additional dialogue options' is the extent of it (and the combat perks, but nothing to do with charisma).

Comment: Thats because your reading under the Fallout 3 and Fallout New Vegas descriptions. The exact description provided for the Fallout 4 perk in your referenced link is *"You're charming... and dangerous. Men suffer +5% damage in combat, **and are easier to persuade in dialogue.**"*. The question is asking if there is a charisma *equivalent* to compare how much easier it is to persuade males in dialogue.

Answer (score -3):

Different authors of wikis and forums say, that this perk is implemented like the one with the same name from Fallout 3. So you will get extra 5% damage per level against male characters and you'll be able to unlock special dialogue options. ([here](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1537174-fallout-4-lady-killer-vs-black-widow/?p=24347616) you will find a description of the perk in Fallout 3)

After completing the game I also didn't find anything about special unlocks or loot when using black widow.

Comment: Not exactly. In the first paragraph I wrote about the most likely statistics behind the perk. The reason I didn't mention the "extra percentage" for charisma is that there won't be such a calculation.

Comment: The first paragraph is about damage. The question isn't about damage, so that doesn't address the question. The question is about the mechanics of the persuasion bonus. The second paragraph addresses this, but appears to be pure speculation.